# VS Code not working on Elementary OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, executable, elementary-os

I have downloaded VS Code on Elementary OS, and I followed the setup instruction of [Setting up Visual Studio Code on linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/setup#_linux).

The executable file "code" seems to be unknown, it is not opening, Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Open a terminal and try `/opt/VSCode-linux-x64/Code`.

Comment: @nephente worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open it by running in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
/opt/VSCode-linux-x64/Code
```

---

If it work you can make a shortcut (so you will only need to run `code` to open Code):

```
sudo ln -s /opt/VSCode-linux-x64/Code /usr/local/bin/code
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft published an official Visual Studio Code package for Linux which is packaged as a snap package. To install Visual Studio Code on Debian-based distributions and other distributions that support snap packages, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install code-insiders --classic
```

A snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged application with full access to the system, and Visual Studio Code extensions are installed into the user's home directory.

As its name suggests Visual Studio Code is a code editor with an embedded terminal, not a full scale IDE, but the latest iteration of Visual Studio Code is a very good code editor.